# Authorization along with Authentication in Route.php : Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

**I have below Route that checks if the user is authenticated and only then let them to access the page**

```
<?php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
], function() {

    Route::get('/Categories-List', 'Skills\Category_Controller@index');
});
```

In my `auth()->user()`, there is `RoleID` to check if the user is Admin or with other role. I want to check if the `RoleID` is 1 then only let them to access the page.

Can I set Authorization along with Authentication in Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so what you need is to create `AdminMiddleware` and add it to routes.

First, open your `User` model and add extra method into it:

```
public function isAdmin() 
{
   return $this->RoleID == 1;
}
```

Now run in console:

`php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware`

open your `AdminMiddleware.php` and change `handle` method so it should look like this:

```
if (!\Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response('Admin account required.', 401);
    } else {
        return redirect('/'); // set here any url you need
    }
}

return $next($request);
```

Now open `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add into `$routeMiddleware` property new entry:

```
'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

Finally modify into your routes

```
'middleware' => 'auth',
```

into

```
'middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin'],
```

The order here is important, if you change order here, you will get unexpected Exception if user is not logged.

Depending on your needs you might also want to use only `isAdmin` middleware here in case for this route you want to make other redirection than in `auth` when user is not logged. In this case you need to merge methods from `auth` and `isAdmin` and fit it to your needs.

Comment: @Helper Is it hapenning when user is not admin? If so, do you have for `/` url defined any middlewares? You should redirect in `AdminMiddleware` to route where you are not using `isAdmin` middleware

Comment: If user is logged but is not admin, and hit route protected by `isAdmin` it will get redirected to `/` and later they will get redirected again to `/` - that's why you get this. You should use in `AdminMiddleware` new route for example `restricted` and create new route `restricted` where you display that this page is restricted only for Admin or you should use redirect to main url for logged user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560621/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-support-facades-validatorresolver

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is run multiple middlewares - one to auth the user and the other one to check his access level.

What you want to do is define the middlewares in the array like so:

```
<?php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth','isAdmin'],
], function() {

    Route::get('/Categories-List', 'Skills\Category_Controller@index');
});
```

You can see I've added a `isAdmin` middleware that would do the check that you need. You only need to create the middleware yourself.

Plenty of other info on middleware on routes here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes