# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::resolver()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

## **What is it about ?**

I am using Laravel 5.2 and update the composer by running the following command

```
composer require felixkiss/uniquewith-validator:2.*
```

and then added the following to your providers array in config/app.php:

```
'providers' => array(
    // ...

    'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider',
),
```

I did this because I am trying to implement Multiple column Unique Validation. I mean Composite Key Validation.

### **[I am following the instructions as mentioned here](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator)**

## **What's the issue ?**

When Laravel runs the below line.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'SubCategory' => 'required|max:25|min:5|unique_with:tblsubcategory,CategoryID',
        'CategoryID' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return \Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($v)
                    ->withInput();
    }
    return Redirect('/SubCategories-List/'.$request->input('CategoryID'));
}
```

I get this error.

> FatalErrorException in UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider.php line 27: Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::resolver()

## **Important**

This was working fine in Laravel 5.1

Comment: remove the backslash from `\Validator`

Comment: if I do that I get error Class `App\Http\Controllers\Skills\Validator` not found

Answer (score 2):

Having the exact same problem, although when I run php artisan commands I get the following error **Class validator does not exist**

Trying to work out whats going on now

-- Fixed (for my problem) --

Updated your composer json to this version ...

"felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "2.0.3"

and remove  Whoops, as that seems to catch the **HttpResponseException** of which the upgrade docs do say could cause issues.

This fixed my issue.